# How can I get the best deal at the auction?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

In Porto Marinada, there are 3 auctions every day, sometimes with a fourth special auction. The starting bids for some of these items are crazy expensive, and the price can only be driven up as people bid. So how can I get the best price?

So far, the only advice I saw is to soft reset the game, but I'm looking for actual in-game strategies. I already know the basics of auctions, like not to bid more than the item or its equivalents are worth elsewhere (e.g. 60k for a golden bottle cap). How does the auction logic even work? Is it random?